# What does "lax" mean in "lax monoidal functor"?

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory

I know that the `Applicative` class is described in category theory as a "lax monoidal functor" but I've never heard the term "lax" before, and [the `nlab` page on lax functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+functor) a bunch of stuff I don't recognize at all, re: bicategories and things that I didn't know we cared about in Haskell.  If it is actually about bicategories, can someone give me a plebian view of what that means?  Otherwise, what is "lax" doing in this name?

Comment: Wrong nlab page. See this https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor

Comment: "Lax" as in "Relax" over the constraint of having isomorphic mempty & mappend.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's switch to the monoidal view of `Applicative`:

```
unit ::     ()     -> f   ()
mult :: (f s, f t) -> f (s, t)

pure :: x -> f x
pure x = fmap (const x) (unit ())
(<*>) :: f (s -> t) -> f s -> f t
ff <*> fs = fmap (uncurry ($)) (mult (ff, fs))
```

For a *strict* monoidal functor, `unit` and `mult` must be *isomorphisms*. The impact of "lax" is to drop that requirement.

E.g., (up to the usual naivete) `(->) a` is strict-monoidal, but `[]` is only lax-monoidal.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how `unit` and `mult`, given here, could be isomorphisms, as it's not clear how `unit` and `mult` can compose, let alone have `unit . mult == mult . unit == id`.

Comment: I don't mean that they are a pair of mutual inverses: I mean that they each have inverses.